# Bosun how to reserve all groups when calculate two numberSet

Tags: monitor, bosun, fiware-bosun

There are two numberSet
numberSetA:
{
"group1": 3
}

numberSetB:
{
"group2": 5
}

how can i get the result like
{
"group1": 3,
"group2": 5
}
when numberSet joining groups, use 0 if the group does not exist in this numberSet

Basic Operators will generate a "unjoined group" when group does not exist in any numberSet, what can i do